# Read an SVG from the assets folder gets error?

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, android-studio-2.2

I'm using Android studio 2.2 and use AndroidSVG SVG rendering library in my Android project. Here is the relevant code section for read particular SVG.

```
// Read an SVG from the assets folder
SVG  svg = SVG.getFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), filename);

// Create a canvas to draw onto
if (svg.getDocumentWidth() != -1) {
   Bitmap  newBM = Bitmap.createBitmap(Math.ceil(svg.getDocumentWidth()),
                                       Math.ceil(svg.getDocumentHeight()),
                                       Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   Canvas  bmcanvas = new Canvas(newBM);

   // Clear background to white
   bmcanvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);

   // Render our document onto our canvas
   svg.renderToCanvas(bmcanvas);
}
```

I've created Assets folder properly but following line shows error on `getAssets()` that cannot resolve method.

```
SVG svg = SVG.getFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), Freesample);
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Well, `Context` has [`getAssets()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets()). Are you sure that `getContext()` is returning an `android.content.Context`? What is `Freesample`?

Comment: @CommonsWare `Freesample` is my svg file name.  `getContext()` is returning an `import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;`

Answer (score 0):

[`getAssets()` is a method on an `android.content.Context` object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets()). According to your comment, `getContext()` is not returning one of those. You need to get an `android.content.Context`, such as your `Activity`, and use that for your `getAssets()` call.